# Identifying the Quotient Space in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If I have:

$X = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$ and 
$A = \{ (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$

identify the quotient space $X/A$ as a more familiar topological space and show its homeomorphic to $X/A$.

Comment: Here $X$ is a sphere and $A$ is its equator. Then the quotient space is two spheres glued together at one point.

Comment: What would the function be of that?

Comment: Topological balloon tricks.

Comment: @user64013 I'm not entirely competent and I'm on the run right now but if there is still no answer when I'm back I'll try to write something useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the unit sphere $X$ to the set $Y=\{(v,w,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid v^2+w^2+(z\pm\frac12)^2=\frac14\}$ which is the union of two spheres with radius $\frac12$ and centers $(0,0,\pm\frac12)$. The easiest way is to map a point $(x,y,z)$ to the point $(v,w,z)$ with same third coordinate. When you imagine those sets, you'll see that $v$ and $w$ are just dilations of $x$ and $y$ by the same factor $\lambda(|z|)$ which only depends on $|z|$. Try to derive a formula for this $\lambda(z)$ by looking at the equations $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $v^2+w^2+(z\pm\frac12)^2=\frac14$.

Answer (score 0):

Show that open disk $D^2$ is homeomorphic to sphere $S^2$ with one point removed. Let $D^2$ be the open disk of radius $1$ centered at the origin in $\mathbf R^3$ and let $S^2$ be the sphere of radius $1/2$ with the south pole at the origin. Let $N$ denote its north pole. Define map $\varphi : D^2 \to S^2 \setminus \{N\}$ as 
$$\begin{cases} (x,y,0) \mapsto (x,y, 1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - (x^2 + y^2)}) & x^2 + y^2 \le 1/2 \\
(x,y,0) \mapsto (1-x, 1-y, 1/2 + \sqrt{1/4 - (x^2 + y^2)}) & x^2 + y^2 > 1/2 \end{cases}$$

Then $\varphi$ is bijective, continuous and open:

Injective: If $(x,y,0) \neq (x', y', 0)$ then either $x\neq x'$ or $y\neq y'$. Hence in both cases, $\|(x,y,0)\| , \|(x', y', 0)\| \le 1/2$ and $\|(x,y,0)\| , \|(x', y', 0)\| > 1/2$ it is immediate that $\varphi ((x,y,0))  \neq \varphi ((x',y',0))$. If $\|(x,y,0)\| \le 1/2$ and $ \|(x', y', 0)\| > 1/2$ then $x^2 + y^2 \neq x'^2 + y'^2 $ and hence in this case also $\varphi ((x,y,0))  \neq \varphi ((x',y',0))$.

Surjective: Let $(x,y,z) \in S^2 \setminus\{N\}$. If $z \le 1/2$ then $\varphi ((x,y,0)) = (x,y, 1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - (x^2 + y^2)}) = (x,y,z)$ since $z = 1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - (x^2 + y^2)}$. Similarly if $z > 1/2$.

Continuous: It is clear that $\varphi$ is continuous if $x^2 + y^2 \le 1/2$ and if $x^2 + y^2 > 1/2$. Hence it is enough to verify that 
$$\lim_{x^2 + y^2 \to 1/2} (x,y, 1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - (x^2 + y^2)}) =  (1-x_0, 1-y_0, 1/2 + \sqrt{1/4 - (x_0^2 + y_0^2)})$$ for $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = 1/2$. This holds since 
by symmetry we may choose to take the limit along $x=y$. Then 
$$\lim_{2x^2\to 1/2} (x,x, 1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - 2x^2 )}) =  (1-1/2, 1-1/2, 1/2 + \sqrt{1/4 - (1/4)}) = (1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$$

Open: Similarly we show that $\varphi^{-1}$ is continuous.

To prove $S^2 \sqcup S^2 / \sim$ is homeomorphic to $X/A$ note that $X/A$ consists of two open disks (all the points whose equivalence class only contains one point) and a point (all points of $A$ are one equivalence class). Similarly, the space $S^2 \sqcup S^2 / \sim$ consist of two sphere (with point removed) and a point. Then there are homeomorphism $\varphi_1$ from one disk in $X/A$ to one sphere minus a point in $S^2 \sqcup S^2 / \sim$ and similarly for the other disk a $\varphi_2$. Let $\varphi$ be the map $[a] \mapsto [N,S]$ where $[a]$ is the equivalence claas of $A$ in $X/A$ and $[N,S]$ is the equivalence class of the north and south pole in $S^2 \sqcup S^2 / \sim$. Then $\varphi_1 \sqcup \varphi \sqcup \varphi_2$ is a homeomorphism.